# Making a new file in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there a way to put a text file into a project in Eclipse without making it a shortcut? I am trying to upload a file into a java project however, it keeps coming up as a linked file rather than just a text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click and drag the file into the project, select copy files, not link files.

Answer (score 0):

You can drag a .text file directly into your project folder in eclipse!